# How to create the formula field value populating from one field to another field

Tags: custom-object, formula-field, customization

Two fields are available in account object

I have the Picklist datatype  Value in one field called custom__c

Picklist Values are:

**atom,
molecule,
organic,
inorganic**

I have created the another formula field called  custom1__c with return type as text

if i create the record in the object

if i choose the value **atom** in custom__c field another field called custom1__c it should populate the **small** value in that field

like wise

if i choose

**atom- small,
molecule - big,
organic - material,
inorganic - nonmaterial**

**should automatically populate in the custom1__c field, can you guide me the answer  what is the formula i have to write when creating the field called as custom1__c as formula for populating the values**

Comment: In your custom1 formula text field, you can use CASE function on the custom picklist field and return the corresponding values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the below formula in the custom formula field `custom1__c`

```
CASE(custom__c, 
"atom", "small", 
"molecule", "big", 
"organic", "material", 
"inorganic", "nonmaterial",
"" 
)
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you normally need to use `TEXT()` or `ISPICKVAL()` to work with a picklist field. However, the `CASE()` formula function is special, and you can use a picklist field directly if it's the first argument (as it is in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your formula something like

```
if(Text(custom__c) == 'atom', 'small', if(Text(custom__c) == 'molecule', 'big',if(...)))
```

But just FYI formula have 5000 characters limits. So for small values it will works for large value you can create a text field and populate that using trigger.